# Please detect the error in my query, I am getting an "Invalid column name" error.

Tags: c#

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=HKGROX-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=example;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        string value = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();

        switch (value)
        {
            case "BJP":
                string s = "select BJP from noofvotes where year= "+ DropDownList2.Text+" and const=" + DropDownList3.SelectedValue + "";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s,con);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                sda.Fill(ds);
                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    DataRow dr = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0];
                    TextBox1.Text = dr["BJP"].ToString();
                }
                break;

        }
        con.Close();
    }
```

Here I am getting invalid column name 'Rohini'. I have a table which feeds the the values to the listboxes.

Comment: YEAR is a reserved keyword. What are the real column names of your table?

Comment: Where are you seeing this error? There's no reference to `Rohini` in this code?

Comment: I suppose `DropDownList3.SelectedValue` contains the value "Rohini", which is not surrounded by `''`, so it is interpreted as a column (`where const=Rohini`). Use parameters as @Steve suggests.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your Columns (year & const) are Varchar2 type then use single quotes.

```
string s = "select BJP from noofvotes where year= '"+ DropDownList2.Text+"' and const='" + DropDownList3.SelectedValue + "'";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s,con);
```

And if Columns (year & const) are number columns you have to use like below:

```
string s = "select BJP from noofvotes where year= "+ Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList2.Text)+" and const=" + Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList3.SelectedValue) + "";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s,con);
```

Answer (score 3):

Supposing that you have columns really named YEAR and CONST I would add, to avoid confusing errors

```
string s = "select BJP from noofvotes where [year]= @yval and [const]=@cval";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s,con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yval",DropDownList2.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cval",DropDownList3.SelectedValue);
....
```

Enclosing the reserved word YEAR in square brackets will allow to use that name as column identifier (while this is really a bad practice). The CONST word is not reserved but I find it confusing as well because of the well known language keyword.

Another problem in your query above (and surely the source of the first error) is the `SelectedValue` property of the DrowpDownList3. It is inserted in the query without enclosing in single quotes. If I imagine that it contains the word `Rohini` then your original text becomes something like this

```
string s = "select BJP from noofvotes where year=2014 and const=Rohini";
```

and, in this way, the value is considered like a column name

Again, putting it as a parameter to the query should resolve the problem.

Comment: `const` isn't keyword. But you can use it in square brackets as well.

Comment: @user1517636 could you explain the edit here as comment?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
"select BJP from noofvotes where [year] = "+ DropDownList2.Text+" and const=" + DropDownList3.SelectedValue + "";
```

Here is list of reserved `Keywords` of `Sql Server`
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238507%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you want a quick fix replace this:

```
string s = "select BJP from noofvotes where year= "+ DropDownList2.Text+" and const=" + DropDownList3.SelectedValue + "";
```

With this:

```
string s = "select BJP from noofvotes where [year]= '"+ DropDownList2.Text+"' and const='" + DropDownList3.SelectedValue + "'";
```

If you want a safer fix, use `SqlParameter`s whenever possible, it will keep hackers away from your database.

```
string s = "SELECT BJP FROM noofvotes WHERE [year]= @year AND const=@const";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s, con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", DropDownList2.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@const", DropDownList3.SelectedValue);
```